# Is it possible to get Windows Repair to restore the latest files at the same time as an image?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, images, restore

Using Backup and Restore from Windows 7 Pro it seems pretty easy to take a an image of a machine and then configure it to backup all files on a disk incrementally. It also seems extremely easy to restore the machine image. However I think the image is restored exactly as it was taken, i.e., without the extra files from the incremental file backups.

I've then tried to manually restore these files but some of them are in use by the operating system which is now running.

Is there a way to tell Windows Repair to restore files from the incrementally backed up files on top of the restored image at the same time, before it boots the restored OS? Otherwise it looks like I would have to then boot the machine with something like HBCD to restore the incrementally backed up files over the top of the restored system image.